# When are rpar and rseq expressions actually computed in Haskell program?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Consider the following program.

```
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

main = do
    r <- evaluate (runEval test)
    print r

test = do
    a <- rpar (fib 36)
    b <- rpar (fib 37)
    return (a,b)

fib :: Int -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Note that we deliberately use an inefficient implementation of Fibonacci generator to make computations take some time. Now we compile this program with GHC:

```
$ ghc rpar.hs -threaded
```

The program takes **3.281s** with `+RTS -N1` flag and **2.126s** with `+RTS -N2` flag. Now we replace `print r` with `print "hello"` in `main` function and compile the modified program in the same way. New program takes **0.003s** with `+RTS -N1` and **0.004s** with `+RTS -N2`. It seems that `a` and `b` in `test` function are not computed in new program.

Then, we modify `test` function in `rpar/rseq` style:

```
test = do
    a <- rpar (fib 36)
    b <- rseq (fib 37)
    return (a,b)
```

We conduct the same experiment on this program. (1) `print r` in `main` function: the program takes **3.283s** and **2.138s** for `+RTS -N1` and `+RTS -N2` flags respectively; (2) `print "hello"` in `main` function: the program takes **1.956s** and **2.025s** for `+RTS -N1` and `+RTS -N2` respectively. Obviously, either of `a` or `b` in `test` is computed in this case.

**I have two questions from this example:**

(1) when are `rpar` and `rseq` expressions actually computed in program? It seems that `(fib 36)` is not instantly computed when `a <- rpar (fib 36)` is evaluated.

(2) if a machine has sufficient CPU cores and we specify `+RTS -N2` flag when running the program, are computations of `a` and `b` guaranteed to start simultaneously (or almost simultaneously) ?

Comment: By the way: Welcome to Stack Overflow! On Stack Overflow if you find an answer adequate please accept it by pressing the checkmark below the answer score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The bigger question is: when are things computed in Haskell?

   Since Haskell is a lazy language we compute a thing only when that thing is demanded. Specifically in your first program if you never demand `r` ([`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) will only compute it to the `(,)` constructor) the `fib` calls are never computed and the parallelism is only overhead.

   In you second program `rseq` will demand the result of the containing computation and therefore it is computed regardless of if you `print` it or not.
2. Running the program with `+RTS -N2` will make the runtime use 2 Haskell Execution Contexts (HECs). The computations `a` and `b` will be added to a spark pool and will be available for either HEC to compute. What happens next is GHC Runtime magic, but if the computations are not too simple you can assume that each HEC will take one spark and compute it.

   For more reading on the RTS check out this collection of papers: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReadingList#DataParallelHaskellandconcurrency (and the run time section), and possible Simon Marlow's http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929

Comment: So, can we say `rpar` evaluates its argument to WHNF (weak head normal form) while `rseq` evaluates its argument to NF?

Comment: `rpar` only sparks the computation, as far as I know it does not force any evaluation while `rseq` will force evaluation to whnf. (For nf you need `rdeepseq`.) In the case of `Integer` I believe that whnf == nf.

Comment: I see. One more question, does `rseq` start the evaluation of its argument instantly?

Comment: Hmm, let's see. `rseq a` will compute `a` to whnf when the containing computation is demanded, so when you `evaluate . runEval` the containing computation `a` will be computed.